# Is it possible to open the numeric keyboard before the text keyboard?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I have an editText that needs to be of the "text" type, but I want that when it gets focus my Android keyboard opens showing the numbers first, instead of the letters that are the default.

I've been researching for a while now, but I can't find an answer. Could anyone tell me if it is possible to do this?

PS: setting my editText to "number" doesn't get me the result I need.

**EDIT**
I need my keyboard to have this behavior when opening: https://streamable.com/2ohsaz ; that is, the user can type whatever he wants, but the numeric keypad option must appear first

Comment: @Unmitigated It's not technically a problem. It's just a question, which I don't know if it's possible to do. I need my keyboard to have this behavior when opening: https://streamable.com/2ohsaz ; that is, the user can type whatever he wants, but the numeric keypad option must appear first.

Comment: @Unmitigated That won't work at all.  That gives the keyboard a hint that it should show only numbers.  Which the keyboard app that the user or OEM has chosen can interpret in a dozen different ways.  Most of them interpret it to mean "no letters at all", but some will put up old school phone number layouts (0-9 with * ad #), some calculator style layouts, (0-9 with +-*/) or anything else the devs thought would be useful.  Most won't allow you to go back to an alphabetic keyboard from that mode, but some will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  THe keyboard is a separate app, and it gets to decide what to show.  There's an API to provide hints to the keyboard, such as NUMBER to tell it that it should show numbers.  But there's no API to tell it to show certain information at certain times.  You can try to hack it by setting the input type, but it will be more likely that a keyboard will ignore or be confused by changing input types, because they aren't actually supposed to change until a new field is focused.

Because the keyboard is a separate app that isn't part of the OS and is frequently replaced by OEMs and users, you can't require special advanced behavior like that-  the API between the app and the keyboard just isn't set up to allow that, and is mostly guided by conventions and expectation.  So any advanced trickery you use will work on some devices, and may totally break others.  As such its recommended that other than setting an initial input type, you let the keyboard do what it wants.